# How to store events in DB when using Event Sourcing?

Tags: c#, event-sourcing

I got to know about CQRS and Event Sourcing  yesterday and about to learn how every single part should be implemented because i want to implement it in a new project.

So in every single sample application for event sourcing i can see that events are stored in memmory, but how do i actually store those events in the DB so i can get them out of the db again and be able to execute if needed?

Comment: There examples if you google it and there are projects that are built for as an event store (in no particular order) - look at these links [EventStore](https://geteventstore.com/) and there's this [article](https://geteventstore.com/blog/20130220/getting-started-part-2-implementing-the-commondomain-repository-interface/); [NEventStore](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore) or you could look at PostgreSQL see [Vaughn's article](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=942) its in Java but you could port to .net

Comment: @ChrisMoutray But in event sourcing, if i change Name of some property and have to update it in db, i just need to create new Event and store this event into DB? or do i also need to update the row in the tabel where name property is stored?

Comment: I can't remember the name of the *pattern* but you're not meant to change the data and instead as you read in the event determine it version and transform/upgrade it to match the changes. Renaming fields is a simple mapping to new name. Missing data is a bit more tricky; if its not important then no problem but if it is then you'd have to calculate/query on the fly (which might hurt performance), so I'd say you can always precompute and lookup from a purpose built view-model/projection (in the same way you'd query for your screens).

Comment: Personally I think you have to be pragmatic and make your changes work for you - eg I'd want to keep things clean and fix typo's in the data before resorting to that transforming pattern ...just don't go down the path of changing the data values within the events